Расчет контрольной суммы С#
Есть код на С#, но так как я его не знаю, хотелось бы увидеть? как на С это выглядит.
Order ID - 2byte; Memo_ID - 2byte; Length - 4byte; Info n byte

Непонятно, как string превращается в int в теле цикла.
// AstrData = {Order ID} + {Memo ID} + {Length} + {Info}
private string GetCheckData(string AstrData)
{
  int CheckSum = 0x00;
  for(int i=0;i<AstrData.Length;i++)
  {
    CheckSum = CheckSum + AstrData[i];
  }
  CheckSum = (CheckSum % 65536);//mod
  CheckSum = (CheckSum ^ 0xFFFF) + 1;
  return CheckSum.ToString("X4");
}

Что означает X4? Хорошую литературу может кто подскажет для изучения С#?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/264178

X4 форматирует число в шестнадцатеричное представление и дополняет его нулями до 4 символов => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-x-or-x-format-specifier

AstrData[i] возвращает char на позиции i, который неявно преобразуется в его числовое значение, когда он участвует в арифметической операции с int (строки-это массивы char-каждый символ имеет значение из unicode = число тоесть)

А зачем вы поставили метку C++?

Это похоже на "Ошибка XY"
